# What is the proper way to test a namespace-qualitified attribute name in a xsl:if?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using xslt 2.0 to test the name of a namespace-qualitfied attribute inside a `xsl:if`. I have a solution working but I believe it is a weak one, being sensitive to the particular namespace prefix. See http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rMs/1 for a working example problem.

Example Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
    <ex:t1>some content</ex:t1>
    <ex:t2>some content</ex:t2>
    <t3 ex:attr1="attr-val-1" ex:attr2="attr-val-2">more content</t3>
</content>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
    <ex:t1>some content</ex:t1>

    <t3 ex:attr1="attr-val-1">more content</t3>
</content>
```

In my stylesheet I am using similar logic to iterate over elements and attributes. In the case of elements, I can test using `self::ex:t1`, but I have to resort to `name()='ex:attr1'` for attributes. If the namespace prefix in the stylesheet is changed from `ex`to `ex1`, this attribute logic fails. `self::` appears not to work for attribute nodes, or at least I haven't been able to get it to work.

> In a `xsl:if` what is the correct way to test for a namespace-qualified
>   attribute name?

My stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns:ex="http://example.com" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ex:*">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <xsl:if test="self::ex:t1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@ex:*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:if test="name()='ex:attr1'">
                <!--<xsl:if test="self::ex:attr1">-->
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Edit:**
In my production system, from which the above problem was abstracted, I ended up using one of the methods suggested by Michael Kay/Martin Honnen: `<xsl:if test=". instance of attribute(ex:attr1)">`. It is clean and directly expresses the intention.

The other solutions function correctly but I disliked the weakly-implied dependency on `..` in `<xsl:if test=". is ../@ex:attr1">` and `<xsl:if test="node-name(.)= resolve-QName('ex:attr1', ..)">`. `<xsl:if test="node-name(.) = QName('http://example.com', 'attr1')">` suffers from having to enter the namespace URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options include

```
test=". instance of attribute(ex:attr1)"
```

or

```
test="node-name(.) = QName('namespace', 'attr1')"
```

or

```
test=". is ../@ex:attr1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Michael. I will check it out.

Comment: All three of these options work perfectly. Is there a simple way to build a QName using the prefix instead of the namespace URL?

Comment: @keithm, you can construct a `QName` using e.g. `<xsl:if test="node-name(.)= resolve-QName('ex:attr1', ..)">`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-resolve-QName.

Comment: But resolve-QName uses the namespace bindings from an element in the source document rather than the stylesheet, so this is sensitive to how the prefix "ex" is declared in the source document. That's surely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

An example is not a substitute for an explanation. The following stylesheet produces exactly the result you asked for - either by design, or by coincidence:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ex="http://example.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove ex:t2 -->
<xsl:template match="ex:t2"/>

<!-- remove ex:attr2 -->
<xsl:template match="@ex:attr2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there is nothing to test for here.

---

And yes, you are correct about the `self::` axis: it will never lead to an attribute (or to a namespace). And no, this has nothing to do with the attribute being in a namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this does not address the specifics of my question, which is about testing attribute names outside the context of a template match. The example is for illustration only. I provided the simplest case I could think of that highlights the apparent difference between testing element vs. attribute names.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "testing attribute names outside the context of a template match."

Comment: I am trying to understand how to formulate a proper 'test' expression for attribute names in a xsl:if or xsl:when element, as I tried to illustrate in the example.